Computing divisors of elliptic curves
I recently have a tough time trying to compute divisors of functions on elliptic curves. This is a part of exercise 11.1. from Washington:

Find the divisor of $g(x,y)=\frac{y^4}{(x^2+1)^3}$ over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ on $y^2=x^3-x$

I started with the finite points. For $y=0$ we have the points $(0,0), (\pm1,0)$ on the curve. Since $y=0$ a uniformizer for these points is $u_P=y$. By
\begin{equation*}
g(x,y)=y^4\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^3}
\end{equation*}
and since the fraction is defined for $x=0,\pm1$, it follows that $g(x,y)$ has a zero of order $4$ in each of that three points.
Now consider $x=\pm i$. We find the points $(\pm i,\mp 2i)$ on the curve. Since $y\not=0$ we can take the uniformizer $u_P=x-x_0$. We get
\begin{equation*}
g(x,y)=(x+i)^{-3}\frac{y^4}{(x-i)^3}
\end{equation*}
where the fraction does not vanish and is defined at $(-i,2i)$. Therefore we have a pole of order $3$ at this point. Analogously at $(i,-2i)$.
So far we have $3\cdot4=12$ roots with multiplicity and $2\cdot 3=6$ poles with multiplicity, right? At this point we have to check the order at infinity. By a theorem we know that the degree of a divisor coming from a function must be zero. Therefore we can conclude that $g$ has a pole of order $6$ at $\infty$. And hence
$$\text{div}(g)=4[(0,0)]+4[(1,0)]+4[(-1,0)]-3[(i,-2i)]-3[(-i,2i)]-6[\infty] $$
Is this correct? My problem is that I have no idea how to deduce the pole of order $6$ at $\infty$ without using the Theorem... I know that the uniformizer is given by $\frac{x}{y}$. However, I am unable to rewrite $g(x,y)$ in a fitting way. I get
$$g(x,y)=\big(\frac{x}{y}\big)^r \frac{y^{4+r}}{(x^2+1)^3x^r}$$
For example for $r=-4$ the numerator equals $1$, but the denominator still has leading term $x^2$ and therefore the fraction vanishes at $\infty$. For $r=-6$ (what is supposed to be right) the denominator equals $1$, but the numerator vanishes.
Can anyone tell me if my derivation of the divisor is correct, and explain me how to deal with the point $\infty$ by hand?
I would really appreciate any help on this!

You've written $g$ differently in two different locations in your post. Is the denominator supposed to be $(x^2+1)^2$ or $(x^2+1)^3$?

I am sorry about this inconsistency, it is supposed to be the third power. I fixed it.

Let $\require{cancel} \newcommand{\ord}{\operatorname{ord}} v = \ord_\infty$ be the order of vanishing at infinity. I'm guessing that Washington has already proved that $x$ and $y$ have double- and triple poles at infinity, respectively, so $v(x) = -2$ and $v(y) = -3$. Then
\begin{align*}
v\left(\frac{y^4}{(x^2+1)^3}\right) = 4v(y) - 3 v(x^2 + 1) = 4(-3) - 3(-4) = -12 + 12 = 0.
\end{align*}
Thus $g$ has neither a zero nor a pole at $\infty$.
With a little algebra, one can even see this more easily. Since $y^2 = x^3 - x$, we can always express a rational function on $E$ using powers of $y$ no greater than $1$. We have
$$
\frac{y^4}{(x^2+1)^3} = \frac{(x^3 - x)^2}{(x^2+1)^3} = \frac{x^6 - \cdots}{x^6 + \cdots}
$$
and clearly the numerator and denominator vanish to the same order at $\infty$.
But this does not cohere with the rest of your calculation. And indeed, you have forgotten two points where $g$ has poles. For each value of $x$ where $x^3 - x \neq 0$, there are $2$ corresponding $y$-values. So $g$ also has poles of order $3$ at $(i, 2i)$ and $(-i, -2i)$ in addition to the ones you noted at $(i, -2i)$ and $(-i, 2i)$.
In general, I usually find it clearer to change coordinates when computing orders of vanishing at the point at infinity. Really, $y^2 = x^3  - x$ is just the equation of the affine patch where $Z \neq 0$ of the projective plane curve $E: Y^2 Z = X^3 - X Z^2$, where $x = X/Z$ and $y = Y/Z$. The point $(0:1:0)$ at infinity is instead contained in the affine open where $Y \neq 0$. Letting $w = X/Y$ and $z = Z/Y$, then $E$ is given by $z = w^3 - w z^2$ on this patch. Rewriting the uniformizer $x/y$ and $g$ in these coordinates, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{y} = \frac{X/Z}{Y/Z} = \frac{X}{Y} = w
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\frac{y^4}{(x^2+1)^3} &= \frac{Y^4/Z^4}{\left((X/Z)^2 + 1 \right)^3} \cdot \frac{Z^6}{Z^6} = \frac{Y^4 Z^2}{(X^2 + Z^2)^3} \cdot \frac{1/Y^6}{1/Y^6} = \frac{Z^2/Y^2}{((X^2/Y^2) + (Z^2/Y^2))^3}\\
&= \frac{z^2}{(w^2 + z^2)^3} = \frac{(w^3 - wz^2)^2}{(w^2 + z^2)^3} \, .
\end{align*}
Noting that $\frac{z}{w} = w^2 - z^2$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{(w^3 - wz^2)^2}{(w^2 + z^2)^3} = \cancelto{1}{\frac{w^6}{w^6}} \frac{(1 - z^2/w^2)^2}{(1+z^2/w^2)^3} = \frac{(1 - (w^2 - z^2)^2)^2}{(1+(w^2 - z^2)^2)^3} \, .
\end{align*}
The point at infinity corresponds to $(w,z) = (0,0)$, and we see that this expression evaluates to $1$ there.
